# background color change when clicked 2x

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onclick

I need a button which can change the background color if you click it 2x.
How can I do this?, I only know how to do it with 1 click.
My code is actually this:

```
<button onClick="document.body.style.backgroundColor ='#000';"> color </button>
```

Comment: You mean when the button is 'doubleclicked' like when opening an app or if it was clicked the second time, no matter how fast?

Comment: no matter how fast

Comment: In that case, accept the Spectric answer. If you don't want to have separated JS block, use: <button onClick="window.clicks = (window.clicks||0) + 1; if (clicks===2) document.body.style.backgroundColor ='#000';"> color </button>

Comment: did work, great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onDblClick` instead:

```
<button onDblClick="document.body.style.backgroundColor ='#000';"> color </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the number of clicks in a variable and add a `click` event listener to the button that increments the counter and checks whether it is `2`, and if so, sets the background color of the body.

```js
var clicks = 0;
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(++clicks == 2){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor ='#000';
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="btn"> color </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the response of @Spectric, store the number of clicks in a variable and add a click event listener to the button.

I don't know logic is what is desired.

You could add another button with an idea equal to the one placed, but in reverse: subtracting.

```js
const btnEle = document.querySelector(".btn");
const resEle = document.querySelector(".result");
const legendEle =  document.querySelector("#legend");

let clickCount = 0;
btnEle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  clickCount++;
  resEle.innerHTML = "The button has been clicked " + clickCount + " times ";
  
  if (clickCount > 1) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor ='#000';
    legendEle.style.color = '#1E5128';
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.result {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<div class="result"></div>
<br />
<button class="btn">CLICK HERE</button>
<h3 id="legend">Click on the above button to check if the button is clicked</h3>
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" onclick="eventB()">
```

```js
function eventB() {
  var click = 0;
  btn.addEventListner('click', function() {
  if(++click == 2){
    window.document.body.style.background = '##836fff';
  }
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is a copy of Spectric answer, but adding bugs. With this code, on every click, will add a new event listener